# Как реализовать построчный вывод из bash?

Tags: php

Есть сайт suip.биз, там к примеру есть nmap, sqlmap и другие программы, как реализовать подобное? явно там не через js сделан вывод

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Попробуйте сформулировать проблему более точно, опишите, что именно вы хотите реализовать, какие трудности возникли при реализации.

Comment: на данном ресурсе можно ввести имя домена и отправить на проверку.
и на слеедующей странице сделан вывод консоли построчно

Comment: с помощью `ob_flush()` в рнр

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изучение языка программирования подразумевает изучение всех его возможностей. Попробуйте ознакомиться с [RTFM](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.shell-exec.php) на [официальном сайте PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/). Да, еще есть функция [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php).

Answer (score 0):

Это имелось ввиду? Потому что на том сайте именно так реализовано (только не через `iframe`, а напрямую)

```
<?php

    // Создать файл index.php с этим кодом

    if(isset($_GET['iframe'])){
        for($i=0;$i<50;$i++){
            ob_flush();
            print "msg #{$i}, ";
            flush();
            usleep(250000);
        }
        die();
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            iframe{
                height: 200px;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Если выполнить напрямую,</p>
        <p>то футер будет загружен после </p>
        <p>полного выполнения PHP-кода</p>
        <p>(В отдельных случаях ломает HTML-разметку)</p>
        <p>Значит грузим через <strong><u><i><?php print htmlspecialchars('<iframe></iframe>') ?></i></u></strong></p>
<!--Тут передадим _GET-параметр 'iframe'-->
        <iframe src="index.php/?iframe"></iframe> 
        <p>Сюда загружаем какой-то футер</p>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`

```
<?php 


set_time_limit(0);

$handle = popen("whoami ", "r"); 

        if (ob_get_level() == 0)          
            ob_start();

        while(!feof($handle)) {          

            $buffer = fgets($handle);
            $buffer = trim(htmlspecialchars($buffer));

            echo  "<span class='vivod'>".$buffer ."</span> ";      
            echo str_pad('', 4096);      
            ob_flush();
            flush();

        }

        pclose($handle);                 


ob_end_flush();    
?>
```

`
Всем спасибо , получилось сделать так))